# With discord.py, whats a way to get my discord bot to display a custom message in the 'playing' section on the members tab?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to display a custom 'now playing' message right below my Discord bots name in the members list.

I looked at open source discord.py bots on GitHub, but it's too complex for me to understand.

This is all i have right now:

```py
bot = Bot(
    command_prefix=when_mentioned_or(BotConfig.prefix),
    activity=Game(name="Commands: c|help")
)
```

I have also read https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html but i cannot find an example for this specific problem.

I would like for something like this to happen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kxMg.png

Thanks, all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: Based on constructor parameter for Client you can't pass activity like that in async branch, you can however do that in rewrite branch. I suggest you move to rewrite since it's better updated.

For your answer, you need to set it later for example in the on_ready method:

```
bot = discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='some game'))
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it is supposed to be marked as the official answer by the OP.

Comment: ty @Sujit , I hope I helped OP even tho he's not responding.

Comment: Yes you did help him... He actually copied your answer and posted it again and called it the answer. The post got taken down a couple of hours ago.

Comment: My issue was that i didn't have bot defined. I changed the bot into client and then it worked, since i had client = discord.Client() . I'll mark it as correct for other people who look at the thread.